# how to upload image to server using both camera and gallery android

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to upload image and it's title to MYSQL server in android. but when i was using gallery to get image it was working fine but now i introduced camera in application it is not working.

I know there are similar questions about this but i was unable to solve my problem.

here is button's code:

```
btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        GetImageNameEditText = textIn.getText().toString();

        ImageUploadToServerFunction();

    }
});
```

here is my select method for image:

```
private void SelectImage(){
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera","Gallery","Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Uploadcamera.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Image");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(items[i].equals("Camera")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);

            }else if(items[i].equals("Gallery")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"),SELECT_FILE);

            }else if(items[i].equals("Cancel")){
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

here is activity result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,requestCode,data);

    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_CAMERA){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        if (requestCode==SELECT_FILE){

            Uri seletecdImageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(seletecdImageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my image upload function and connection code :

```
public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject ;

    byteArrayOutputStreamObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStreamObject);

    byte[] byteArrayVar = byteArrayOutputStreamObject.toByteArray();

    final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Uploadcamera.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

            super.onPostExecute(string1);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
            Toast.makeText(Uploadcamera.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.
            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

            HashMapParams.put(ImageName, GetImageNameEditText);

            HashMapParams.put(ImagePath, ConvertImage);

            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ServerUploadPath, HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;
        }
    }
    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();

    AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
}

public class ImageProcessClass{

    public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnectionObject ;
            OutputStream OutPutStream;
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriterObject ;
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderObject ;
            int RC ;

            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnectionObject = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnectionObject.setReadTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setConnectTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoOutput(true);

            OutPutStream = httpURLConnectionObject.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriterObject = new BufferedWriter(

            new OutputStreamWriter(OutPutStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriterObject.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

            bufferedWriterObject.flush();

            bufferedWriterObject.close();

            OutPutStream.close();

            RC = httpURLConnectionObject.getResponseCode();

            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReaderObject = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnectionObject.getInputStream()));

                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String RC2;

                while ((RC2 = bufferedReaderObject.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilderObject;

        stringBuilderObject = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {

            if (check)

            check = false;
            else
            stringBuilderObject.append("&");

            stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilderObject.append("=");

            stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilderObject.toString();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your app crashing?

Comment: `it is not working.`. Is a bad error description. And if you have NullPointerExceptions then mention them in your post directly. If your app crashes than tell that!

Comment: Put as first lines in onClick(). `if(bitmap==null){Toast( .. bitmap==null...); return;}`.

Comment: It seems that 'NullPointerExceptions` ruin your days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628334/error-while-uploading-image-to-mysql-server-android

Comment: You are using that `bitmap` variable there for the first time. It appears nowhere else in your code. So why would it contain a bitmap? You did not put one in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Volley

```
 private void uploadImage_Server(String url) {



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Your API Response

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {


                        //Showing toast for API error or timeout error
                        Toast.makeText(Imageupload.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters like that
                parameters.put("key", value(image in base64);


                //returning parameters
                return parameters;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Imageupload.this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put your error log or what response you are getting

Comment: sure  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.bakarunlimited.twistmunch.Upload.Uploadcamera.ImageUploadToServerFunction(Uploadcamera.java:237)
                                                                                 at com.bakarunlimited.twistmunch.Upload.Uploadcamera$1.onClick(Uploadcamera.java:88)

Comment: first one here ImageUploadToServerFunction(); and second one here                               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStreamObject);